# A more generic Functor class

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functor

This question may seem a little bit silly, but I'll ask it first then explain the rationale behind it.

Lets say we redefine `Functor` in the following way:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class Functor a where
  generic_fmap :: a

instance Functor ((a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b) where
  generic_fmap f (Just x) = Just (f x)
  generic_fmap _ Nothing = Nothing

instance Functor ((a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]) where
  generic_fmap = map

-- etc with more instances
```

And then, I've considered two approaches for the definition of `fmap`.

(1):

```
fmap :: (Functor ((a -> b) -> f a -> f b)) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
fmap = generic_fmap
```

or (2) (which needs undecidable instances) (**Edited**):

```
class Functor f a b where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

instance (GenericFunctor ((a -> b) -> f a -> f b)) => Functor f a b where
  fmap = generic_fmap
```

Besides the increased typing and ugliness, is there anything we lose defining `fmap` in either of these ways?

The reason I'm asking is that I've found that the standard `Functor` class is more specific than the mathematical definition, so many things that otherwise would fit as functors can not be functors in Haskell. My idea was to define a very generic `Functor` class (perhaps not as generic as above though). But by making it too generic you'd lose type inference. So then users can decide to use different versions of `fmap` depending on whether they need generality or type inference. Much like how users can choose between `.` in prelude (that only works on standard functions) or `.` in `Control.Category` (that works on all categories).

I know there's a bunch of backwards compatibility problems also, but my first question is, are my definitions identical to use for instance *users* (not worrying about those who want to define instances for the moment).

Comment: You edited your question to add `a` and `b` arguments to `Functor`. That makes it a very different question: Now it is possible to define with GHC (and my original answer no longer applies to this version). However, at the same time, the answer to your question now is a definite *no*: there are now many *uses* that stop working, namely any where you *don't* want to provide `a` and `b` as fixed ahead of time. Also even when it still works, all type signatures need to change.

Comment: Is none of the various available generalisations to the `Functor` class (\[[1](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hask-0/docs/Hask-Category.html#t:Functor)\] \[[2](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-category-0.6.1/docs/Data-Category-Functor.html)\] \[[3](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.1.1/docs/Control-Functor-Constrained.html)\]) general enough for you?

Answer (score 4):

As far as can ascertain, your definition doesn't work in current GHC, even with `UndecidableInstances`.

The problem is you would need a hypothetical extension "`RankNConstraints`" which would allow you to mention `a` and `b` in your last instance declaration despite that they're not in the head of it, e.g. as

```
instance (forall a b. GenericFunctor ((a -> b) -> f a -> f b)) => Functor f where
```

I've thought for a while that this extension would be great to have, for this and many other purposes (e.g. Stackoverflow answers keep coming up where it would have seemed relevant). And so have many others, since at least 2000 when SPJ and Ralph Hinze suggested it [in a paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/derive.htm).

Unfortunately, I recently learned from an [old GHC ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2893) that it's unknown how to implement it sanely because it wreaks havoc with type inference.

Comment: Isn't this addressed (at least partially) by [Data.Constraint.Forall](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints/docs/Data-Constraint-Forall.html)?

Comment: @dfeuer I'm afraid the version on Hackage is [broken](https://github.com/ekmett/constraints/issues/11). There's a new version on GitHub which is safe (as far as we know) but cannot be as automatically inferred.

Comment: Och. Sad. Nice work implementing `unsafeCoerce`. I wish I understood it. What weakness did you find?

Comment: @dfeuer The `Forall` trick depended on there being no way to distinguish when a constraint "holds for two hidden concrete types `A` and `B`" from when it "holds for all types". Unfortunately type equality constraints break this assumption, and type families make it possible to escalate this to `unsafeCoerce`. (A closed family is a bit easier - the first, more complicated version [can be adapted](http://oerjan.nvg.org/haskell/Forall/UC3.hs) to an open one. Possibly GADTs might work too.)

Comment: @dfeuer Oh and for the simplest version most of the remaining complexity is about splitting everything into small enough, sufficiently well-hidden steps that GHC doesn't see enough at a time to realize something's horribly wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I think the bigger problem here is that a `Functor` is not only a `map`, but a few laws that go with it. I don't see how you could express the laws for the `GenericFunctor` you propose.

For example, `id` and `(.)` in `Category` define what identity and composition means - now you could define a `GenericFunctor` for a pair of `Categories`.